# Simple recursion for the A129179

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

- Let $T(n,k)$ be [A129179](https://oeis.org/A129179), i.e., an integer coefficient with generating function
  $$
  G(t,z) = 1 + zG(t,z) + tzG(t,t^2z)G(t,z)
  $$
  Other generating functions are $\frac{1}{G_1(t,z,0)}$ and $\frac{1}{G_2(t,z,0)}$:
  $$
  G_1(t,z,j)=1-t^{2j}z-\frac{t^{2j+1}z}{G_1(t,z,j+1)}, \\
  G_2(t,z,j)=1-\frac{t^{2j}(1+t^{2j+1})z}{1-\frac{t^{4j+3}z}{G_2(t,z,j+1)}}
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R(n,q)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q+q\operatorname{mod}2+1}z^jR(n-1,j), \\
  R(0,q)=1
  $$

I conjecture that
$$T(n,k)=[z^k]R(n,0)$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
T(n)=local(CF=1+x*O(x)); for(j=0, n, CF=1 - z^(2*(n-j))*x - z^(2*(n-j) + 1)*x/CF); polcoeff(1/CF, n, x)
R_upto(n)=my(v1, v2, v3); v1=vector(2*n+1, i, 1); v2=v1; v3=vector(n+1, i, 0); v3[1]=1; for(i=1, n, for(q=0, 2*(n-i), v2[q+1]=sum(j=0, q+q%2+1, z^j*v1[j+1])); v1=v2; v3[i+1]=v1[1];); v3
test(n)=R_upto(n)==vector(n+1, i, T(i-1))
```

Is there a way to prove it?